# xml drawable and android layout

Tags: android, xml, layout

I have a big problem. 
How could I code this
design:

[image]

This is the code of that border

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromDegrees="90"
android:toDegrees="90"
android:drawable="@drawable/start_borderbottom"/>
```

and `start_borderbottom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="line">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorStartDivider" />
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="@color/colorStartDivider" />

</shape>
```

I tried different variations of linearlayout, relativelayout, and cannot find exact solution, always something overlaps. When I add DrawableBottom to my loginTextView the border doesn't render. How to add this border and is it better to use relativelayout or linear?

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to add this xml as background

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#B36ABE" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:bottom="5dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#7B0A8D" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

if you have any problem then let me know